# Convert visual build pipeline in yaml file

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I'm working with Azure DevOps pipeline and I'm using the visual designer.

But there is also the YAML file. I would like to export my Build pipeline into a YAML file. It seems to be possible like mentionned in this Github issue (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/2504) using the `View YAML` button.

But this button is disable in my project (I cannot click on it):

[image]

I don't know how to enable it. The preview feature `New YAML pipeline creation experience` is enabled. I'm using some Task that are tagged as `Preview`. Can it be a reason?

Does someone know why it is disabled and how to enabled it?

Comment: is it actually saved? are there no errors?

Comment: Yes the pipeline is saved and there are no errors. The pipeline is working well

Comment: never saw that, try relogin in incognito mode?

Comment: Doesn't change anything

Comment: probably a support ticket :)

Comment: If you create a new empty build definition, the option is enabled?

Comment: Just tried it. I started from an empty job with the visual designer and the option is still disabled

Comment: I opened an issue on github. Wait & see..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also have the same problem for several projects on pipeline level:
[image]

Try to check the agent level. It may be available:

[image]

Comment: Thanks it works. What's the difference between the pipeline level and the agent level ?

Comment: I do not see big differences between the pipeline and agent level. The pipeline level contains additional strings: "resources: - repo: self"

Answer (score 0):

FYI you will shortly be able to export the entire pipeline to YAML (the ability to export individual tasks will be removed);

- https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/replacing-view-yaml/