# Version Control for Azure Pipelines

Tags: version-control, azure-devops, devops

Is there any way to store the azure pipelines in repo and keep track of changes we do on pipelines?

currently I'm planing the following, but like to know any better solutions available?

1. creating pipelines for sql database deployment
2. generate yaml and save it to file
3. commit on to git

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you're using YAML pipelines, YAML pipelines go into source control. The tool solves your problem automatically, by design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use classic pipeline, you can:

1. Generate yaml of existing pipelines: [Convert visual build pipeline in yaml file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54744207/convert-visual-build-pipeline-in-yaml-file/54747591)
2. Create new yaml build and use code from step 1.
3. Yaml build will be committed into source control.